# How to calculate theoretical long-term projected savings for a DIY solar powered fridge?

Tags: electrical, solar-panels, solar, cost-effective

I went on energystar [dot] gov and used their product finder to find the lowest "annual energy use" compact refrigerator. For my use, that turned out to be the FURRION - FCR43ACA-BL which has an estimated 151 kWh/yr annual energy usage rating. I then wanted to run this off of one solar panel. Now I'm new to solar, so I also need a battery, an inverter, and a charge controller.

What I'd like to know is after expenses

```
(1) solar panel
(2) battery
(3) inverter
(4) charge controller
```

at what point, in practice, does this pay itself off compared to PG&E at $0.12/kWh? I mean, if 1-4 costs, say, $300, then if the fridge is costing me $18.12/yr from PG&E to run, then does that mean it takes 16.5 years to pay off? If so, then can I get 1-4 low enough to make the investment worth it? Paying it off in 3-4 years seems worth it but 1-4 isn't going to cost $72.48.

Comment: Hrm...I wonder if this isn't the only approach to a solar fridge...thermal solar + intermittent absorption comes to mind...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, what, like [this](https://oup.silverchair-cdn.com/oup/backfile/Content_public/Journal/ijlct/1/2/10.1093/ijlct/1.2.127/2/1-2-127.pdf?Expires=1509169177&Signature=ayizI7MP9tKQvHJnbHXoewbovSUCtwlv~o2kpy~MYskZ5ERMhghMGOZH4KukN4iZc9W0eLb7fwpqZWfCNj7JmsOMVpRXZmr~-2j1AIBEwwITwM4SlC1TZOO5wp22LMygEzV2lyLrMDvRwj4dNtbRZeYR8z3UR9Z7bwoOUNxSozaSUWm9n7WV161FZEDpS8Qo2HPPmUhCLAdzdeuKQi9ORPYCgKiXELSInLF07zkXE3PBaReT-~22wV4740ZT2x43BWw7WywpnB4D4jxVykdwDn2JuXj6Cr0Etd4JoC4LDP8m-ed~nSEYY~m7V8dTwO3HUrBJejMOcNR4EpRflV2PJg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIUCZBIA4LVPAVW3Q)?

Comment: This reminds me of the guy who used to run to work behind the bus to save the bus fare.  He decided to run behind a taxi to save more money.  :-)  Solar is expensive energy as an investment.  Plus, if you're using it for food that can spoil, you need to keep it running for the longest expected period of no sunshine (a stormy day with night on either side is a long time).

Comment: @fixer1234, oh, no, not at all. I'm just testing locally for a commercial application, if that makes sense.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question: By your criteria the investment is worthwhile when 1-4 (incl. installation etc) cost < $72. It is unclear to me what you expect an answer to look like.

Comment: You need to normalize yearly energy usage by volume. That refrigerator "FURRION - FCR43ACA-BL" is only 4.3 cu ft but uses 151 kWh/yr so it uses 35.12kWh/yr for each cubic foot. Larger refrigerators use more in total but less per cubic foot, and so are more efficient. The more mass you have in it the longer it takes for it to warm, if the refrigerator can go without power at night, you only need batteries or more panels to make up for overcast days.

Comment: @DanD. Except you really, really don't want to be bottoming a set of batteries, unless you are using an exotic type which is resilient to bottoming like NiFe.   Lead-acids are the value battery and they are especially sensitive, best not to use more than 30% of tgeir nameplate range on a dailt basis.   So to save money on batteries you need more intelligent controllers to know when to shed load to protect the battery.

Comment: OP what is your motivation for doing this? Are you hoping to knock some money off your electric bill?  Protect food from blackouts? Install in a remote location with no power? What?

Comment: Right. I had intended to point out that it costs less to store cold as ice than as electrical energy in a battery. The idea was to forgo batteries and use the solar power as it is generated to make ice.

Answer (score 2):

You've ignored two major factors:

Batteries don't live forever, and require maintenance as well as periodic replacement - more so if they are abused (typical when people save money on batteries and then over-discharge them.) This is one reason that "grid-tied" solar is far more common where the grid is available - it eliminates the battery storage and its related costs and labor costs.

The second is harder for most people to grasp - if you paid the $19 dollars to run the fridge, and invested the rest of the $300, how much would that investment yield in 16.5 years? It's a little hard to know for certain since guaranteed bank interest is in the doldrums, but typical returns for sensible investments are near 5% - which would nearly pay your next year's power bill, and if there was any growth in the investment, you might end up making more per year than the power bill comes to.

Comment: Good point, particularly your second point, which, I mean, give "most people" a break, it's not that hard to grasp. It's weighing the benefits between having physical capital or paying for a service with invested interest.